# Python script to find a path around volume, given a slope?

Tags: scripting, modifiers

I'm wondering if there's a script to draw a path around a volume given a slope (for instance 5.8% (= 3.3°)).

Manually, I can draw such a path, but I need to adapt reference point from time to time, like in real life with a theodolite.
[image: manual path finding]

Maybe, using 4 boolean operations with plane, one for each direction, and only keeping the vertices, then again, incrementing vertice position, then joining them together?
[image: plane cut]
Hope it makes sense.

Do you know about an existing script?
Or can you explain me how to deal with resulting vertices after a plane boolean op? Can I "snap to vertex" to prevent adding vertices in the process?

Thanks!

More details in https://blenderartists.org/t/least-cost-path-for-blender-terrains/1226571/3

EDIT: Here's a terrain with an empty for a village location.
[blend file](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/Adn9ETlXQ3MNOvZL4jkwyKWnP2o.blend)

Find the path to the peak!

Comment: Given example add curve extra objects loxodrome spiral, shrinkwrap in X and Y onto landscape.

Comment: To clarify if the objective is to get as "high" as possible, but never climb above a certain grade. Would find global max, set as target. The result (for example terrain shown) is quite likely a more direct route to higher peak and tacking up the mountainside  This is related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174727/place-objects-on-mesh-using-snap-with-python-script/175503#175503  The "foot" can be used to choose way to go. For a question like this recommend adding a terrain blend for testing purposes.

Comment: Thank you! The spiral projection doesn't work the same way for real landscape. It could work for simple volumes though. Thanks for the link, I'll see that tomorrow. I'll add a terrain