# Get height value at specific x and y coordinate via script

Tags: python, coordinates

It may be simple but I don't get it to work. I have ground objects and several other objects that should stand on the ground. These other objects are automatically positioned. The x,y coordinates are fixed here, but the z coordinate has to be adapted so that the objects really stand on the ground.

What is the best option here? Use object.ray_cast or search for nearest vertices in the area of x,y?

Comment: It would help if you posted your script.

Comment: Could be finding the lower vertex in z, from the plane or world point of view. Could you illustrate the situation with some images?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174727/place-objects-on-mesh-using-snap-with-python-script

Answer (score 1):

Precisely speaking you need some sort of **collision detection** look at [this book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Real_Time_Collision_Detection.html?id=66KsDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description) and [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection) for more info.

Roughly speaking *ray casting*  is a good way; but be careful about optimization.I suggest you to compare x-y bounding boxes of your *objects* and *groundObjects* (using `bpy.data.objects['Cube'].bound_box`
). If they overlap each other do raycasting for each vertex of your objects on the overlapping *groundObjects* and choose the *shortest one*.