# Snapping multiple vertices from one mesh to the z axis of another mesh's vertices

Tags: mesh, snapping, svg

I have a mesh that is mountenous terrain. I also have an svg dataset with the houses that belong on that terrain. But that second dataset has no height invormation. Now I got my mountainous terrain as one mesh in blender and I imported the svg data as one mesh.
Is there a way to snap all the vertices from the buildign data set mesh to the surface of the topographical mesh without doing one by one? There are tousends of houses.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174727/place-objects-on-mesh-using-snap-with-python-script  Since houses are generally level to ground a method is to set origin of house to ground and shrinkwrap it and a "skirt of verts" to surface, to make it look like it is on a flat foundation,  rather than overhanging.

Comment: The Problem is, my houses are not objects, It's one entire mesh. So I would need to tell the vertices of the buildings-mesh to place themselves on the z axis where to topographic meshes vertices are. But I am not that well versed in Python for Blender.

Comment: Can they be separated eg P Loose Parts ?